# Doxygen default comments

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation, code-documentation

is it possible to define something like macros in Doxygen?

I want write a comment something like this:

```
/**
 \return return_self_reference
 */
```

and Doxygen will replace `return_self_reference` with a string defined by me.

The comment that would then be read by Doxygen would be this one:

```
/**
 \return A reference to the instance that the operator was called on.
 */
```

Please note that, alltough I called it a macro earlier, I do not want to define a C macro or anything like that in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen has for these cases the configuration parameter `ALIASES`.

Lets take the following example:

```
/** \file
  */


/**
 * \return the normal version
 */
int fie0(void);

/**
 * \return \str1_repl
 */
int fie1(void);

/**
 * \str2_repl
 */
int fie2(void);
```

and set the following `ALIASES` in the doxygen configuration file (see also the manual for more possibilities of `ALIASES`):

```
ALIASES                = "str1_repl=just the text in replacement" \
                         "str2_repl=\return return and the text in replacement"
```

and we will get the following result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for!